# Is it possible to write any function in the form of self composition of another function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to know if it is possible to write every real-valued function as the self composition of another function. The statement of the problem might be:

Prove or disprove that for every real-valued function $f$ there exists a real-valued function $g$ such that $f(x)=g(g(x))$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That statement in your post does not quite match your title. $f(x) = g(h(x))$ is also "in the form of composition", and you can always write any function in that fashion by taking $g=f$ and $h$ to be the identity function on the domain of $f$.

Comment: No. https://mathoverflow.net/q/17614/27465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Torsten Schoenberg pointed out above, the answer is **no**, and this is addressed at the sister site [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffx-gx); since duplicate-closure doesn't work across sites, I'm posting this reference (and community-wikiing it) to move the question off the "unanswered" list.

*(Don't let this detract from the fact that it's an excellent question, though!)*